# How can i input a table as an array?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I need to input a data file (below):

```
        14        16        18        20        22        24        
        27        30        35        40        45        50

        8         10        11        12        13        14        
        16        18        21        24        27        30

        0.4       0.5       0.5       0.5       0.5       0.5        
        0.6       0.6       0.6       0.6       0.6       0.6

        16        17        18        19        20        21        
        22        23        25        26        27        29

        2.0       2.2       2.2       2.3       2.4       2.5        
        2.6       2.7       2.8       2.9       3.1       3.2

        1.7       1.8       2.0       2.2       2.4       2.5        
        2.8       3.0       3.4       3.8       3.8       3.8
```

Where when selecting column one those vales will be outputted.

Here is my code; can anyone see any errors?

```
void TimberType() {

    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("TableOfValues.txt", ios::in );
    string TimberValues;
    inFile >> TimberValues;
    inFile >> bendStr >> tensPara >> tensPerp >> compPara >> compPerp >> shear >> mElasModPara >> elasMod5Para >> mElasModPerp >> mShearMod >> density >> mDensity;


    cout << "Please enter timber type " << endl;
    cout << "C14 = 1        C16 = 2        C18 = 3        C20 = 4" << endl;
    cout << "C22 = 5        C24 = 6        C27 = 7        C30 = 8" << endl;
    cout << "C35 = 9        C40 = 10    C45 = 11    C50 = 12" << endl;
    cin >> timberType;

    {
        switch (timberType) {
        case 1:
            timberType = 1;
            cout << "You have selected timber type C14" << endl;
            cout << TimberValues[1];
            break;
        case 2:
            timberType = 2;
            cout << "You have selected timber type C16" << endl;
            cout << TimberValues[2];
            break;
        case 3:
            timberType = 3;
            cout << "You have selected timber type C18" << endl;
            cout << TimberValues[3];
            break;
        case 4:
            timberType = 4;
            cout << "You have selected timber type C20" << endl;
            cout << TimberValues[4];
            break;
        case 5:
            timberType = 5;
            cout << "You have selected timber type C22" << endl;
            cout << TimberValues[5];
            break;
        case 6:
            timberType = 6;
            cout << "You have selected timber type C24" << endl;
            cout << TimberValues[6];
            break;
        case 7:
            timberType = 7;
            cout << "You have selected timber type C27" << endl;
            cout << TimberValues[7];
            break;
        case 8:
            timberType = 8;
            cout << "You have selected timber type C30" << endl;
            cout << TimberValues[8];
            break;
        case 9:
            timberType = 9;
            cout << "You have selected timber type C35" << endl;
            cout << TimberValues[9];
            break;
        case 10:
            timberType = 10;
            cout << "You have selected timber type C40" << endl;
            cout << TimberValues[10];
            break;
        case 11:
            timberType = 11;
            cout << "You have selected timber type C45" << endl;
            cout << TimberValues[11];
            break;
        case 12:
            timberType = 12;
            cout << "You have selected timber type C50" << endl;
            cout << TimberValues[12];
            break;

        }

        cout << "Bending Strength: " << bendStr << "N/mm^2" << endl;
        cout << "Tension in Parallel: " << tensPara << "N/mm^2" << endl;
        cout << "Tension in Perpendicular: " << tensPerp << "N/mm^2" << endl;
        cout << "Compression in Parallel: " << compPara << "N/mm^2" << endl;
        cout << "Compression in Perpendicular: " << compPerp << "N/mm^2" << endl;
        cout << "Shear: " << shear << "N/mm^2" << endl;

    }
}
```

At the moment I am just receiving 0 values for Bending Strength, Tension in Parallel, Tension in Perpendicular, Compression in Parallel, Compression in Perpendicular, and Shear.

Any ideas will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The two errors I see are 1. you are not checking if you input was successful, 2. you are using `std::endl`. To me it looks as if you input fails at some point but why this is the case I can't tell without the declarations of the various variables.

Comment: how can i check if my input is successful?

Comment: It input failed one of the state bits on the stream will be set and converting the stream to a Boolean value fails. Typically it looks something like this: `if (in >> value0 >> value1) { process_succesful_input(value0, value1)); }`

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, you can use an array to read the values into
    const int ROW = 12, COL = 6;
    int table[ROW][COL] = {};
    istream file("TablesOfValues.txt");

```
for(int i = 0; i < ROW && file; ++i){
  for(int j = 0; j < COL && file; ++j){
        file >> table[i][j];
  }
}

//now tables[0][0] = 14
//now tables[1][2] = 35
//added a slash to first comment
```

Comment: This would be placed after you *successfully* open the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
       #include <iostream>
        #include <array>

        string elem[12][7] = {
        //First column is the row number (assuming they're related to timber so starting at 1)
        // Please note these are strings
        { "1",   "14",  "16",   "18",  "20",  "22",  "24"  }
        { "2",   "27",  "30",   "35",  "40",  "45",  "50"  }
        { "3",   "8",   "10",   "11",  "12",  "13",  "14"  }
        { "4",   "16",  "18",   "21",  "24",  "27",  "30"  }
        { "5",   "0.4", "0.5",  "0.5", "0.5", "0.5", "0.5" }
        { "6",   "0.6", "0.6",  "0.6", "0.6", "0.6", "0.6" }
        { "7",   "16",  "17",   "18",  "19",  "20",  "21"  }
        { "8",   "22",  "23",   "25",  "26",  "27",  "29"  }
        { "9",   "2.0", "2.2",  "2.2", "2.3", "2.4", "2.5" }
        { "10",  "2.6", "2.7",  "2.8", "2.9", "3.1", "3.2" }
        { "11",  "1.7", "1.8",  "2.0", "2.2", "2.4", "2.5" }
        { "12",  "2.8", "3.0",  "3.4", "3.8", "3.8", "3.8" }
        }

     void TimberType ()
        {
            ifstream inFile;
            inFile.open ("TableOfValues.txt", ios :: in);
            string TimberValues;
            inFile>>TimberValues;
            inFile>>bendStr>>tensPara>>tensPerp>>compPara>>compPerp>>shear>>mElasModPara>>elasMod5Para>>mElasModPerp>>mShearMod>>density>>mDensity;


            cout << "Please enter timber type " << endl;
            cout << "C14 = 1        C16 = 2     C18 = 3     C20 = 4" << endl;
            cout << "C22 = 5        C24 = 6     C27 = 7     C30 = 8" << endl;
            cout << "C35 = 9        C40 = 10    C45 = 11    C50 = 12" << endl;
            cin >> timberType;  

        {
            switch (timberType)
            {
            case 1:
                timberType = 1;
                cout << "You have selected timber type C14" << endl;
                cout << TimberValues [1];
                break;
            case 2:
                timberType = 2;
                cout << "You have selected timber type C16" << endl;
                cout << TimberValues [2];
                break;
            case 3: 
                timberType = 3; 
                cout << "You have selected timber type C18" << endl;
                cout << TimberValues [3];
                break;
            case 4:
                timberType = 4;
                cout << "You have selected timber type C20" << endl;
                cout << TimberValues [4];
                break;
            case 5:
                timberType = 5;
                cout << "You have selected timber type C22" << endl;
                cout << TimberValues [5];
                break;
            case 6:
                timberType = 6; 
                cout << "You have selected timber type C24" << endl;
                cout << TimberValues [6];
                break;
            case 7:
                timberType = 7;
                cout << "You have selected timber type C27" << endl;
                cout << TimberValues [7];
                break;
            case 8:
                timberType = 8;
                cout << "You have selected timber type C30" << endl;
                cout << TimberValues [8];
                break;
            case 9:
                timberType = 9; 
                cout << "You have selected timber type C35" << endl;
                cout << TimberValues [9];
                break;
            case 10:
                timberType = 10;
                cout << "You have selected timber type C40" << endl;
                cout << TimberValues [10];
                break;
            case 11:
                timberType = 11;
                cout << "You have selected timber type C45" << endl;
                cout << TimberValues [11];
                break;
            case 12:
                timberType = 12; 
                cout << "You have selected timber type C50" << endl;
                cout << TimberValues [12];
                break;

            }

// This is the code you need to edit to search the array

void searchString(string A[],int size, string target)
{
    int j;
    {
    for(j=0; j < size; j++)
        if(A[j] == target)
            cout << A[j] << endl;
        else cout << "Not Found";
    }
}


            cout << "Bending Strength: "<< bendStr << "N/mm^2" << endl;
            cout << "Tension in Parallel: "<< tensPara << "N/mm^2" << endl;
            cout << "Tension in Perpendicular: "<< tensPerp << "N/mm^2" <<endl;
            cout << "Compression in Parallel: "<< compPara << "N/mm^2" << endl;
            cout << "Compression in Perpendicular: "<< compPerp << "N/mm^2" << endl;
            cout << "Shear: "<< shear << "N/mm^2" << endl;

        }
        }

I believe there is a simple search command that will let you reference the timber numbers based on their number. Please post the final code here because I'm actually working on something like this and would love to know how it worked for you.
```

Comment: Your indentation is a bit off.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions:
Replace `switch` with table lookup:

```
struct Timber_Text_Entry
{
    unsigned int index;
    char const   text;
};

const Timber_Text_Entry Timber_Type_Names[] =
{
    { 1, "C14"}, { 2, "C16"}, {3, "C18"}, {4, "C20"},
//...
};
const unsigned int NUMBER_OF_TIMBER_TYPES =
    sizeof(Timber_Type_Names) / sizeof(Timber_Type_Names[0]);

// Printing the menu contents:
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_TIMBER_TYPES; ++i)
{
  cout << Timber_Type_Names[i].text
       << " = "
       << Timber_Type_Names[i].index;
  if ((i % 4) == 3) cout << "\n";
}

// The switch statement replaced:
if ((timberType > 1) && (timberType <= NUMBER_OF_TIMBER_TYPES))
{
    // This should search for the index == timberType instead
    // of using timberType as an index into the array.
    // The code below assumes the order of the entries will
    // not change.
    // The "-1" is because timberTypes start at 1 and the
    // array indices start at 0.
    cout << "You have selected timber type ";
    cout << Timber_Type_Names[timberType - 1].text;
    cout << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "Invalid timber selection: " << timberType << endl;
}
```